# Error in preg_match PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

```
<?php

$str = "asd,ad";
if(preg_match(",",$str)) { 
    echo "ok";
}

?
```

It outputs me

> No ending delimiter ',' found in....

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing delimitters, try this:

```
$str = "asd,ad";
if(preg_match("/,/",$str)) { 
    echo "ok";
}
```

To find out more instances, you may want to use `preg_match_all` function too.

Answer (score 2):

your pattern can be replaced to `strpos` instead

```
if(strpos($str, ",")!==false)
{
   echo "ok";
}
```